# Required Field Message using Zod Library as Schema based in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Can anyone help me to get the solution. I am trying to display the Required Error Message for an input field. It shows only Minimum length Error not hitting the Required message on Submitting the form

```
const schema = z.object({
     name: z
       .string({ invalid_type_error: "This is required fiedl" })
       .min(3, { message: "Atleast 8 Characters" }),
});

type FormData = z.infer<typeof schema>;

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<FormData>({ resolver: zodResolver(schema) });
 console.log(errors.name);
```